# VBA 6 + how to export variable to click button

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

I created the following VB6 code and I created two controls on my form - `Combo1` (listbox) and `Command3` (a button).

When I select an item from the `Combo1` list I assign a string to the form scoped variable `param` and display it in a message box and then dismiss it.

But when I then click on the `Command3` button and try to display the same `param` variable in a message box then there is no value stored.

Here's my code:

```
Dim param As String

Sub Form_load()

    Combo1.AddItem "linux ver"
    Combo1.AddItem "linux ver"

End Sub

Sub Combo1_Click()

    If Combo1.ListIndex = 0 Then
        param = "linux 5.1"
        MsgBox param
    End If

    If Combo1.ListIndex = 1 Then
        param = "linux 5.5"
        MsgBox param
    End If

End Sub

Sub Command3_Click()

    MsgBox "param" & param

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your question is off topic for Serverfault. It may be on topic for [Stackoverflow](http://Stackoverflow.com) but check their [faq](http://Stackoverflow.com/faq) and [search](http://Stackoverflow.com/search) their site before asking.

Comment: hi @lain please send my quastion to stackoverflow ,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is due to [Variable Scope](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb6-variable-scope). You need to define "param" outside of the Combo1_Click() subroutine, because as it stands, param only exists and is accessible within that routine.

Comment: I define it - but still command3_click not print the param value?

Comment: @yael Well, where did you define it? Did you read (and understand) the link I posted?

Comment: I define it outside of Combo1_Click() as your suggestion , but still I not get the value -:( ,

Comment: Well, as it's off topic for SF I'm not really sure how much time I should spend bumping this, but the issue is definitely variable scope. Can you post your new code?

Comment: Try turning on "Option Explicit" as explained here. I find it helps narrow down issues with variables:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4120/discussion-between-dan-and-yael)

Answer (score 0):

What if Combo1.ListIndex is -1? Or 2?

Your param variable would never be assigned, and the behavior you see is exactly what is expected.